# Get the last modified blob and not all blobs

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

Here I list all blobs of the blobstorage. But I only want to return the last blob in the `blobs` and not all blobs.

how can I modified this code to return the last added blob to blobstorage and not everything?

```
async function main() {
   
    let i = 1;

    
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {

     
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
    
      const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
      const download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
     
      blobs.push(download)

     

    }
    return blobs
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Azure Event Grid, you can get Last BLOB modified, it is built on pub\sub model with retry and filter functionality.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal